# Bootstrap Horizontal Form not vertical

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I would like to create a form and have it vertical. However on my computer the fields are all inline:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-offset-3">
        <form role="form" ng-submit="submit()" ng-controller="formCtrl">
            <div class="col-sm-6 form-group">
                <input type="email" data-ng-model="form.email" placeholder="your@email.here" class="form-control">
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6 form-group">
                <input type="password" data-ng-model="form.password" placeholder="password" class="form-control">
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4 form-group">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">sign in</button>
            </div>
        </form>
        <div id="messages"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I would like a slightly more narrow form as seen in the code. `class="form-horizontal"` does not help at all. Picture below shows the result!

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reduce the parent container class to `col-sm-3` and increase the child container's class to be `col-sm-12`.

So the parent container will have `25%` width while the child containers will occupy the full width(`100%`) of the parent.

Readjust the centering of the form by modifying the `offset-*` classes.

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
    <div class="col-sm-3 col-sm-offset-4">
        <form role="form" ng-submit="submit()" ng-controller="formCtrl">
            <div class="col-sm-12 form-group">
                <input type="email" data-ng-model="form.email" placeholder="your@email.here" class="form-control">
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-12 form-group">
                <input type="password" data-ng-model="form.password" placeholder="password" class="form-control">
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4 form-group">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">sign in</button>
            </div>
        </form>
        <div id="messages"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Works! However now the form is not in the middle anymore but slightly off to the left!

Comment: You will need to adjust the `offset-*`  classes. Something like `col-md-offset-5` or `col-sm-offset-5`

Comment: Veeeery close to center. I wonder why bootstrap makes this task so difficult :/

Comment: You did however answer my initial question so :) I'm to make a new post of padding and centering!

Comment: No problem :) What is the browser support you are expecting? If >=IE10. You can add `display: flex` and `justify-content: center;` to `.container`. Remove the offset class afterwards.

Comment: I unfortunately have to support somewhere in the regions of <=IE10 :( Can't wait till all of these old browsers become obsolete!

Comment: BTW use `col-sm-offset` instead of `col-md-offset` since the later will introduce the margin-left only on medium devices.